# Understanding Group Action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

In general are we just supposed to make an educated guess about what the $G$-set is for a group action is if it's not specified?  Here are two examples of what I mean.

I am asked to find a fixed point for the dihedral group of the square.  Typically when I think of group action on a square, I think that the symmetries are moving the vertices around.  However, if I see it that way, then there is no fixed point for the square.  Am I supposed to instead take the $G$-set to be the set of all points in the square, so that the origin is a fixed point?

Similarly, would the $G$-set for $S_{4}$ be the set $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$?  So then the orbit of 1 is $\{1,2,3,4\}$ because, for instance, $i*1 = 1$ and $(12)*1 = 2$ and so on?

Comment: In general it should be clear from context, and if it's not then the writing is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Given a group $G$ and $G$-set $X$, but where we are not told the $G$-action, in general you can't deduce how $G$ acts on $X$. Sometimes it should be clear from context: $S_4$ acts naturally on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and $D_4$ acts naturally on the vertices of a square. However, we also about a $G$-action from $D_4$ on the vertices of a square by having each element act as the identity.

When we talk about fixed points on group actions, we normally talk about the fixed points of a single element of $G$. For example, the nontrivial rotations in $D_4$ have no fixed points.

Comment: Ah, the question I have actually asked (as a sub-question) "Can you realize the rotation group $C_{4}$ of $D_{4}$ as the stabilizer of a fixed point?"  I assumed this meant that there is a fixed point, and we need to find it.  Perhaps the answer is just "no".

Comment: The orbit of any vertex is the entire set of vertices. By Orbit-Stabiliser, the size of the stabiliser of any vertex is 2, so the stabiliser must be isomorphic to $C_2$, the cyclic group of order 2. Indeed, the stabiliser is given by the identity and the flip going through that vertex.

Comment: I think both the fixed points of a single element and the fixed points of the whole action are important concepts. Consider, for example [property FA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_property_FA).